# The ts() function in R is returning the correct start and frequency but not end value which is 1 and not 179

Tags: r

I need help converting a column of 179 observations from an excel file that holds 2 variables (days and values). After i try converting the dataframe with ts(as.vector(a1dataraw['x'], the vector returns with start=1 but also end=1 when it should be 179?

Can someone please identify where im going wrong?

```r
library(TSA)

#Load data 
a1dataraw <- read.csv("assignment1data2024.csv", header=TRUE)
a1dataraw

#Convert to TS

a1data <- NA
a1data <- ts(as.vector(a1dataraw['x']), # Read correct column, which is 'x' here.
  start= 1)

a1data
```

[image: Code input]

[image: Code output]

The end value is 1 when it should be 179? The csv file has 2 columns with headers Trading days and x for the observations

data sample it goes up to 179 trading days:
[image: sample]

Comment: Please post sample data as text that can be copy-pasted, rather than as images. [For many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), users will be much more likely to help if you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that doesn't require users to transcribe your image first just to be able to see where things are going awry. You can use `dput()` or `dput(head())` to provide sample data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

- the data in the question is an image so no one can reproduce it without tediously retyping it.  Even then this does not guarantee that one would have exactly what you have.  In the future please provide a minimal reproducible example  in text form using `dput`.  See the information at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page for guidance on posting.
- there is no point in assigning NA to `a1data` because it is just overwritten in the next line anyways as if it had never existed
- `as.vector(a1data['x'])` is a one element list whose sole component contains the vector `a1data$x`.  That is why it thinks you have one element.

Assuming that the time index is consecutive integers starting at 1 all we need is

```
ts(a1data$x)
```

For example, using the first 3 rows of the built-in data frame `BOD` which has 2 columns named `Time` and `demand`

```
BOD3 <- BOD[1:3, ]
BOD3
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 2    2   10.3
## 3    3   19.0

ts(BOD3$demand)
## Time Series:
## Start = 1 
## End = 3 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1]  8.3 10.3 19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the parameter `end` and setting the length of your series should do the trick.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
x_ts <- ts(x,start=1,end=length(x))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Unfortunately, it didnt work. I tried end=length(a1data) which refers to the initial df, also end=length(a1data['x']) which refers to the specific column, and also tried making end = 179, but it returns 179 different vectors not just 1. I feel like somethings going wrong when I do   a1data <- ts(as.vector(a1dataraw['x']) , its not reading the column correctly I think

Comment: Can you provide a data sample ?

Comment: Just added one in the initial enquiry